# Golang Не могу разобраться с методом вызова dbus

Tags: golang

Мне необходимо добавить ip адрес в зону Trust фаервола. Написал код, пытаюсь использовать библиотеку. Однако код при вызове метода обращения к DBUS странным образом подвисает и выход только по контролС. В гите по коду смог найти только вставки самой библиотеки. К сожалению я пока что больше эксплуататор чем разработчик, не ругайте сильно.
Привожу свой код как есть. Это прототип. Остановка после e03. Спасибо всем кто откликнется, уже неделю веду борьбу за работоспособность.

````
package main

import (
"fmt"
"log"
"net"
"github.com/godbus/dbus"
)

func AEnableIp (ipin string) {

```
ipaddr := net.ParseIP(ipin)

stipaddr := fmt.Sprintf("%s", ipaddr)

var CallMethod string = "org.fedoraproject.FirewallD1.config.zone.addSource string:'"+stipaddr+"'"

fmt.Println(CallMethod)

log.Println("e01")

//использую как dbus.SystemBusPrivate так и dbus.SystemBus

conn, err := dbus.SystemBusPrivate()
//conn, err := dbus.SystemBus()

log.Println(conn)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}

log.Println("e02")

obj := conn.Object("org.fedoraproject.FirewallD1", "/org/fedoraproject/FirewallD1/config/zone/9")

log.Println("e03")

call := obj.Call(CallMethod, 0)

log.Println("e04")
if call.Err != nil {
    panic(call.Err)
}
```
}

func main() {
var ipset string = "192.168.200.200"
AEnableIp(ipset)
}
````

Comment: Может зависает из за того что вы пытаетесь подключиться к системной шине, а у вас нет прав. Попробуйте запустить код от `sudo`

Comment: Эх, если бы. полный рут, судо, все испробовал. Тут же запускаю dbus-send - всё проходит. Есть мысль передавать на обработку утилите dbus-send, но хотелось красивое решение без костылей.

Comment: Кто-нибудь вообще работает с System Dbus или может это мертвая технология и не стоит с ней связываться?

Comment: Решил переписать на механизме dbus-send из моей сессии метод с вызовом данной утилиты прошли. Значит дело не в правах. Пока буду переписывать под утилиту, потом возможно оформлю отдельную либу, взяв метода из Си проекта dbus которым пользуется dbus-send

Comment: Всем привет. Удалось разобраться. Во первых вызов Private System Bus создается с аутентификацией и функцией hello о чем написана документация. Во вторых передача ip адреса происходит отдельным аргументом вот так call := obj.Call(CallMethod, 0, stipaddr) где последний аргумент stipaddr и есть передаваемый ip адрес. Удачи.

Comment: Если вопрос решен, оформи как ответ и поставь галочку что бы другие знали что проблема решена.

Answer (score 0):

Всем привет. Удалось разобраться. Во первых вызов Private System Bus создается с аутентификацией и функцией hello о чем написана документация.
Выглядит вот так:

```
conn, err := dbus.SystemBusPrivate ()
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}

if err = conn.Auth(nil); err != nil {
    conn.Close()
    conn = nil
    return
}
if err = conn.Hello(); err != nil {
    conn.Close()
    conn = nil
}
```

Во вторых передача ip адреса происходит отдельным аргументом вот так call := obj.Call(CallMethod, 0, stipaddr) где последний аргумент stipaddr и есть передаваемый ip адрес. Удачи.